# What does this simple code do?

Tags: ruby, regex

Can anyone explain to me what does the following **Ruby** code do?

```
VARIABLE.scan /\((.+)\)$/
```

**P.S.**

If `VARIABLE=4`,  I got `[]`

If `VARIABLE='aa'`, I got `[]`

What does the code do???

Comment: Can you explain what does the scan() method do?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/\((.+)\)$/
```

The `$` is the end-of-line anchor. The outmost `()` pair is escaped, so they will match literal parenthesis in the string. `.+` matches one or more characters.

So the regex matches strings that end with a parenthesis group with at least one character in it, like:

```
qdqsqsddq(1)
sqkldj(azeazeza)
```

and captures the text in that group.

(Note that it also matches `qsd(qsdq(qsdq)`, and "returns" `qsdq(qsdq` in that case, so its usefulness is a bit questionable.)

Answer (score 2):

```
/    # Regex delimiter
\(   # Match "("
(.+) # Match and capture one or more (+) characters (.), except newlines
\)   # Match ")"
$    # Match the end of the line (before any newlines, if present)
/    # Regex delimiter
```

`.scan()` searches through the string and adds all match results to an array.

So, in effect, it gives you an array of all the lines in a multi-line string, starting from the first opening parenthesis in the line, up to a closing parenthesis at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to add to the others posts:

```
If VARIABLE=4, I got []
```

This actually throws exception. You need to have VARIABLE="4" (NOTE: string. Fixnum does not have such method).

I also put in some examples:

```
"(4)".scan /\((.+)\)$/ # -> [["4"]]
"(42342)".scan /\((.+)\)$/ # -> [["42342"]]
"abracadabra (42342)".scan /\((.+)\)$/ # -> [["42342"]]
"abracadabra (42342) (23)".scan /\((.+)\)$/ # -> [["42342) (23"]].

# The regex do not match new lines by default.
"(4)\n(5)\n".scan /\((.+)\)$/ # -> [["4"], ["5"]]. 
"(4)\n(5)\n".scan /\((.+)\)$/m # -> [["4)\n(5"]]
```